# Vue js - Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue.js and trying to create a custom component that uses jQuery [formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/) plugin. When I include the component file inside another component, I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in /resources/js/form-builder.min.js

I created a custom component with name `formBuilder.vue`. Here is the component code:

```html
<template>
   <div class="content">
      <formBuilder/>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   // import './jquery.min.js';
   // import './jquery-ui.min.js';
   // import './form-builder.min.js';
   export default {      
       created() {

       },
       data() {
           return { 

           }
       },
       mounted() {
         jQuery(this.$el).formBuilder();
       },
       methods: {
       }
   }
</script>
```

In `app.js` file, which is placed in `resource/js/app.js`, I am calling this vue to be recursively used by other components:

```js
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('./bootstrap');
require('admin-lte');
require('./datatable');
import router from './router';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-vue';
import FullCalendar from 'vue-full-calendar';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css'
import Vue from 'vue';
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import './form-builder.min.js';
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(FullCalendar);
Vue.use(CKEditor)
Vue.component("vue-datepicker", Datepicker);
Vue.component('FormBuilder', require('./components/tools/formBuilder.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

This is the component file where i am using formbuilder component

```
  <template>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Questionnaire</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <FormBuilder/> <!--- used formbuilder component --->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        created() {
        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

I have attached the error [image: screenshot] as well.

Can you guys help me find where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing an object into Vue's app JS doesn't automatically produce that object for use by other components.

There are at least two ways to do this (though I recommend avoiding all this and just importing `jQuery` in the components that need it):

**Option 1: `Vue.prototype`**

In your app JS, add jQuery to the `Vue` prototype after you import it, which will make it accessible to every component using the syntax `this.jQuery`:

```
Vue.prototype.jQuery = jQuery
```

**Option 2: `window` object**

Alternatively, you could add it to the window object after importing and use it like `window.jQuery`:

```
window.jQuery = jQuery
```

**Option 3: Individual imports**

It's probably more readable/maintainable to simply import it in components that use it:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```

and then you can use it with the syntax in your example.

Comment: Only option 2 worked for me.

Comment: @Nowdeen - All three work, you may have made a mistake trying to implement the others or perhaps your programming environment is restricted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me (Vue 3)
for some reason i had to stop the cli and restart

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Eslint may return "Unexpected top level property" "$". You will need to insert an exception in your package.json

```
"env": {
    ...
    "jquery": true,
 },
```

It is important to know that jquery will only be available in .vue files. Therefore, your extensions and libraries may report an error. In these cases you will have 2 options:

1. Transform libraries into a .vue template
2. Make a local import on top of them.

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```